# React Component not rendering within Bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Each of my tabs and tabpanels are being displayed; however, the furniture components are not being rendered. Is there a major problem in the way I am trying to implement this?

```
    <Tabs defaultActiveKey={Object.keys(this.state.fTypes)[1]} transition={false} >
    {Object.keys(this.state.fTypes).map((key, value)=>{
      const furniturePieces = Object.keys(this.state.fTypes[key]);
      return(
        <Tab eventKey={key} title={key} style={{width: '100%', height: '100px', backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>
        {this.renderTabDisplay(furniturePieces, key)}
        </Tab>
      )
    })}
  </Tabs>

    renderTabDisplay(furnPieces, key){
furnPieces.map((piece, info)=>{
  const furniturePiece = this.state.fTypes[key][piece];
  return(
    <Furniture
    furniture={furniturePiece}
    inGrid={false}
    conversion={0}
    />
  )
})
```

}

Comment: can you show our full code?

Comment: I attached it in an image in my original post. click on the enter image description link to see. (ignore '=' on line 41 inserted during screenshot by accident)

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning from `renderTabDisplay` add a return to your function.

```
renderTabDisplay(furnPieces, key){
  return furnPieces.map((piece, info)=>{
  const furniturePiece = this.state.fTypes[key][piece];
  return(
    <Furniture
    furniture={furniturePiece}
    inGrid={false}
    conversion={0}
    />
  )
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through your below piece of code i can see you are not returning anything.

//Added return to it and it's working.

```
renderTabDisplay(furnPieces, key){
return furnPieces.map((piece, info)=>{
  const furniturePiece = this.state.fTypes[key][piece];
  return(
    <Furniture
    furniture={furniturePiece}
    inGrid={false}
    conversion={0}
    />
  )
})
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you all!! I can't believe that was it!